Built-in audio on Lenovo legion 16IAX7 running Ubuntu 24.04 not working
I've got a lenovo legion 16IAX7 running Ubuntu 24.04 (kernel 6.8.0, also tried 6.8.7) My alsa info is here . alsamixer shows pipewire, nvidia, and intel soundcards, none of which produce sound from the builtin speaker. Bluetooth sound however is ok.  sudo alsa force-reload doesn't help, and neither does modifying /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf by adding lines
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
blacklist snd_soc_avs

Applying 'verbs' from this kernel patch also hasn't worked.
Possibly related, I find that
systemctl status --user pipewire
gives an error
mod.jackdbus-detect: Failed to receive jackdbus reply: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.jackaudio.service was not provided by any .service files

The hardware listed here refers to a Realtek® ALC3306, while alsamixer and the system profile from alsa info report the ALC287, perhaps this is the source of the problem?
The built-in sound works fine on the windows partition, can someone shed light on how to get it working in ubuntu?

My audio works, despite having the same mod.jackdbus-detect: Failed to receive jackdbus reply: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.jackaudio.service was not provided by any .service files error. Perhaps it has nothing to do with the issue?

perhaps, I've no idea
